# Django: QuerySet error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a test view where one of the data aggregation queries throws an eror that I don't understand. I would appreciate it if someone could comment on this and point me in the right direction. This is my first django project and I'm traversing the learning curve so please bear with me:

Code:

```
biz_group = BusinessGroup.objects.get(group_manager=user)
group_team = BusinessGroupToTeams.objects.get(group_id=biz_group.group_id)
```

which throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
     return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in get
     num = len(clone)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 90, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in iterator
     for row in compiler.results_iter():
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
     for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 58, in execute
     six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
     return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    DatabaseError: column businessgroup_to_teams.id does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT "businessgroup_to_teams"."id", "businessgroup_to_teams"...
```

The BusinessGroupToTeams model looks like this:

```
class BusinessAreaToTeams(models.Model):

    group_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535)
    team_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessgroup_to_teams'
```

I am not querying on "id" and have no model field of "id". Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: django automatically create an id field in each model. Check your database for businessgroup_to_teams table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to define a crossover table with `BusinessAreaToTeams`. Instead of having group_id and team_id be DecimalFields which contain the raw ID, you should define

```
group = ForeignKey(BusinessGroup)
team = ForeignKey(BusinessTeam)  #  guessing the model name here
```

This will create a group_id and team_id field in your table and will allow you to manage the relationship easily using django's QuerySets. Please take a look at [Chapter 10 of the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html) for an introduction to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

here you have not mention any primary key so the django automatically created a primary key
 name id.
here you can make your primary key like this:

```
group_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535, primary_key=True)
```

it will then make the group_id as primary key.